# SQL select WHERE & LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

Our website is built on TWIG templates to generate similar pages depending on table content in database. There is an issue selecting entries based on value present in another table.

4 different pages (destinations) are generated from the same template and I want to add links to sub pages (packages) inside them with "for each" tag, filtered by which page (destination) is currently open. The database structure of packages contain field destination_id.

If the destination_id is set to constant value it works like a charm but only packages with the set ID are displayed as in this example here.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`,`name`,`price`,`days`,`preview`,`permalink`,`main_image` FROM package WHERE `destination_id` = 1 ORDER BY `od` DESC";
```

I have tried multiple variations of WHERE and LEFT JOIN clauses; however, I'm still unable to find a way to make it work as intended.

Full code here:

```
public function DestinationSeperate() {
    global $dbh,$twig,$data;
    $seperate = Process::getSingle('destination',$data['path']['argument'][1],'permalink');
    if($seperate){
        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`name`,`main_image`,`videoid` FROM destinationimage WHERE `destination_id` = ? AND `disabled_bool` = 0 ORDER BY `od` DESC";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($seperate['id']));
        $images = $query->fetchAll();

        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`name`,`permalink`,`main_image` FROM destination WHERE `disabled_bool` = 0 ORDER BY `od` DESC";
        $destination = array();
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            $destination[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'permalink' => $row['permalink'],
                'image' => $row['main_image'],
                );
        }
        $sql = "SELECT `id`,`name`,`price`,`days`,`preview`,`permalink`,`main_image` FROM package WHERE `destination_id` = 1 ORDER BY `od` DESC";
        $package = array();
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
            $package[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'price' => $row['price'],
                'days' => $row['days'],
                'preview' => $row['preview'],
                'permalink' => $row['permalink'],
                'image' => $row['main_image'],
                );
        }
        print $twig->render('default/destination.seperate.html.twig', array('data' => $data,'seperate' => $seperate,'destination' => $destination,'images' => $images, 'package' => $package));
  }
```

Comment: Could you give us some examples of the database and the data you would like to receive from a query?

Comment: also whats the issue with just poutting the destination id in where you've got `WHERE `destination_id` = 1`

Comment: you can see it in action here
http://diveclubmaldives.com/destination/maafushi

each tile has image + link + text and i would like them to be filtered by ID which is the same as ID of the current page.

If i set it to constant number as in the example, it works; however, it loses its purpose as there are 4 different pages that display the same content rather than filtering it by the ID

Comment: When you don't set a static id (=1 in your example) what have you been setting it to for it to be dynamic?

Comment: I have tried using LEFT JOIN as outlined here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) as it was the closest thing i could find related to this issue. I have also tried to include table.column name with WHERE statement in similar synthax as used with left join

Comment: not asking about what join you are using. What variable are you using to make the `WHERE \`destination_id\` = 1` dynamic

Comment: `destination_id` = ? - similar as how destinationimage is fetched
`destination_id` = destination.id - table.column
on top of that i also tried selecting data from both tables and filtering it with the each function but none of what i tried gave the intended result

Comment: and still asking the question.. WHAT variable are you using, what variable do you bind to this...

Comment: the table "destination" contains row "id" which is unique for every entry. Table "package" contains row "destination_id" to be able to link multiple packages to the same destination. I want to link them together so the packages that have the same "id" as the destination page that is currently open would be displayed